# a native JS quick way to check for existing attribute=property?

Tags: javascript, attributes, selector

2 part question

1) what's the quick/simplest way to check for an attribute set to a specific value?

i have a JQuery loop that appends 
    data

.. i needed to test for duplicates.. therefore i have this JQuery code running  w/ the loop to check for duplicates before appending at the moment:

```
$("#team_list .teams[teamName='blahblah']").html()
```

this works perfectly fine actually but..  (my 2nd question)

2) im looking for a more JS native way to do this... because if my script has to process 1000 appends, that's 1000 Jquery calls w/c is slower than native JS .. and since each JQuery selection creates an new object, that's 1000 new objects in memory .. or AM I TOTALLY OFF w/ my performance concerns here?

Comment: Why are you doing so much stuff clientside? Is there any way you could offload and optimize this serverside?

Comment: So you wanna check whether an attribute is defined in a tag or not using javascript...??

Comment: @Blender, well for several reasons..for one, this append "<li teamName=''> part can be called more than once on the same page so i need to make sure contacts added into the actual list is NOT ALREADY THERE.. doing this in the backend means i have to fetch all the li items and their teamName attribute and send to php/backend and then back again.. not practical when i can just check for an existing teamName attribute in the specific div of interest

Comment: @PrasathK - yes , if there's an easier way via plain JS, that doesnt need to create another object taking up space.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`element.hasAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.hasAttribute) method followed by [`element.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute).

Comment: thanks but that's pretty much the same effect as the jquery im already using.. as i've read the hasAttribute thing, it creates an object just like the jquery call.. 

Im really just lookin for a simple function that just gives me a simple booleon true/false if the specific attribute teamName='1111' is set /used already.. if there is such a function.. something like  AttributeExists(teamName,'1111) or something

Comment: This is a DOM method; I don't think it gets much simpler than this.

Comment: hmm.. i see.. thanks for that.. but compared to my existing jQuery line
    $("#team_list .teams[teamName='blahblah']").html()

is this any better? atleast the jquery thing is 1 line in my code .hmm